# Alternative strategies to using push notifications on React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am developing an app that would alert the user of a new event. The latter can be in the form of an API that can be queried via a fetch on the timestamp.

Since push notifications on react native are not yet ready for android (that I know of, but feel free to contradict me!),  can I use an alternative strategy to alert the user of the new event? For example, let's say I would be polling my server every 5 mins, how can I alert the user if a new record is inserted when the app is running in the background?

Comment: I dare to challenge your claim about **"push notifications not supported by Android"** with: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-onesignal. We have used it with success in our project for Android.

Comment: I dare to challenge your claim too :)
I've used this package successfully for push notifications on Android : https://github.com/oney/react-native-gcm-android

Comment: @zvona: I will give Onesignal a look, although not a big fan of MBaaS, but this one looks serious (I just don't want to follow the path of Parser).

Comment: @G.Hamaide I have looked into that module but looks very undocumented. Do you have an example application which can help me understand its integration perhaps? I would be very grateful if you did.

Comment: @Jamez, what do you mean by undocumented ? I suggest you try and install it, do the config, it works like a charm if you follow their instructions. From what I recall, the only *hacky* part, comes with the remote notifications (I'd be glad to help you if you have trouble with them).

Comment: OK I managed to work out the remote notifications part - as you said, there were some config trickery involved. I will post a blog post documenting my workflow for the sake of other readers.